# How to fix the wrong address fill in text input after select from Google Places autocomplete?

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, google-api, google-places-api, google-places

I'm using Google Places API with autocomplete to make a form with address for user. The autocomplete show up the list of address and it contains an address that i want to choose, but after i choose the option, the address filled in input text with a wrong address string. As i see, it's not wrong address number, it's also wrong the street name, when i console the `getPlace()` on event `place_changed` the address also be changed like the google call the api for one more time.

So is this a bug of Google API or something wrong with my code?

***EDIT:**
Here is my directive code for handle google place autocomplete:

```
app.directive('googleplace', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function ($scope, element, attrs, model) {
            $scope.gPlace = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(element[0], {types: ['geocode']});
            google.maps.event.addListener($scope.gPlace, 'place_changed', function () {
                var position = $scope.gPlace.getPlace();
                if (!position.geometry) {
                    alert("Address is not available: ' " + position.name + " '");
                    return;
                }
                if (map && marker) {
                    if (position.geometry.viewport) {
                        map.fitBounds(position.geometry.viewport);
                    } else {
                        map.setCenter(position.geometry.location);
                    }
                    marker.setPosition(position.geometry.location);
                } else {
                    initMap(position.geometry.location.lat(), position.geometry.location.lng());
                }
                updatePosition(position.geometry.location.lat(), position.geometry.location.lng(), input_count, element[0].id);
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Example: I type in the input an address string `55a 3/2, Ninh Kiều, Cần Thơ, Vietnam`, the autocomplete also have that result in dropdown list, but when i choose that address, the Autocomplete fill a wrong address into input text. The address string become `55 Mạc Thiên Tích, Xuân Khánh, Ninh Kiều, Cần Thơ, Vietnam`.

Comment: When asking a question, people will be better able to provide help if you provide code that they can easily understand and use to reproduce the problem. See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: So sorry for mistake, i've updated my description. Could you please check and give me some advise? Thank you :)

Answer (score 4):

This behavior is also shown in Google's Autocomplete example https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete

It looks like these 2 addresses point to the same place ID, so it may be an API issue. I recommend you send feedback to Google Maps, see https://support.google.com/maps/answer/3094045?hl=en&ref_topic=3093612

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for replying. I also see some people have faced a same problem and i think i'll really hard to give feedback to Google when we have same problem with a lot of address... :(

Comment: @StevenDang it's definitely worth trying. I suggest you make a list of all the locations you've found incorrect in Google place autocomplete (not just in your own implementation for geocode types) and then send feedback to Google Maps. Good luck!

Comment: I found the problem, it's base on the ````input_count```` variable in the directive, i saw that i did not assign ````input_count = 1```` so the function ````updatePosition()```` call the ````reserveGeocode()```` one more time, then it causes the wrong address....=D

Comment: Glad to hear! :)